# where to get a smart FileFilter?

Tags: java

I'm trying to find an implementation of `java.io.FileFilter` which understands patterns like these: `"**/*.xml"`, `"src/**/*.java"`, etc. Do you know any package that can provide such a filter (`commons-io` doesn't do this, or I can't understand how).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out [DirectoryScanner](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/core/trunk/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/DirectoryScanner.java?view=markup) from the Ant project.  It does not implement FileFilter but it does recognize those types of patterns.

Answer (score 0):

This notation is used in  [ant](http://ant.apache.org/). So your best bet will be ant.jar

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `FileFilter` does help you here. It is used for evaluating files in one directory when passed to listFiles(...). You seem to want to search through sub directories.